# Column Ambiguously Named error despite addressing which table the columns come from

Tags: database, oracle

I'm getting the Ambiguously named column error when trying to run this code. I don't understand why?

I googled and found that this error can occur when using columns with the same names, but I've specified which tables each column comes from which I believe is meant to fix it.

```sql
INSERT INTO A2ERROREVENT (ERRORID, SOURCE_ROWID, SOURCE_TABLE, ERRORCODE, FILTERID, DATETIME, ACTION)
SELECT 1, ROWID, 'A2CUSTBRIS', 167, 4, CURRENT_DATE, 'MODIFY'
FROM a2custbris cb, a2custcategory cc
WHERE cb.custcatcode NOT IN cc.custcatcode;
```

Expected results: No error
Actual result: ambiguous error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `ROWID`. Which table does it belong to? Is it `a2custbris` or `a2custcategory`?

If you specify `rowid`'s source, it'll work:

```
SELECT 1, 
       cb.ROWID,          --> this
       'A2CUSTBRIS' ...
```

Though, what do you need it for? ROWID can change so you might (and will) lose information which row holds the source information. Perhaps you'd rather store primary key(s), not `ROWID`(s).

---

Also, although it won't fix this very problem, try to switch to current ANSI standard when joining tables. Keep joins separately, move conditions to `WHERE` clause. It makes code somewhat easier to understand, so yours might look like

```
FROM a2custbris cb JOIN a2custcategory cc
  ON cb.custcatcode NOT IN cc.custcatcode
```

Though, Oracle still internally rewrites "new" ANSI compliant code to its "old" syntax (such as outer join; it still uses the old `(+)` operator) but nonetheless, doesn't cost much to *try*.

---

**[EDIT: why you got too many rows?]**

As I don't have your tables, I'll use Scott's EMP and DEPT. Your query looks like this:

```
SQL> select e.rowid, d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename, e.deptno
  2  from dept d join emp e on d.deptno not in e.deptno
  3  order by d.deptno, e.ename, e.deptno;

ROWID                  DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME          DEPTNO
------------------ ---------- -------------- ---------- ----------
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAK         10 ACCOUNTING     ADAMS              20
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAB         10 ACCOUNTING     ALLEN              30
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAF         10 ACCOUNTING     BLAKE              30
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAM         10 ACCOUNTING     FORD               20
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAL         10 ACCOUNTING     JAMES              30
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAD         10 ACCOUNTING     JONES              20
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAE         10 ACCOUNTING     MARTIN             30
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAH         10 ACCOUNTING     SCOTT              20
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAA         10 ACCOUNTING     SMITH              20
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAJ         10 ACCOUNTING     TURNER             30
AAAE5mAAEAAAAGeAAC         10 ACCOUNTING     WARD               30
<snip, as the result returns 42 rows>
```

How to read it? Query says: give me rows from the `DEPT` table whose `deptno` column doesn't exist in `deptno` column of the `EMP` table. Reviewing the result, you can see that we have ACCOUNTING department (10) which is "paired" with values from the `EMP` table whose department isn't 10 but (20, 30).

The same goes for all other rows in both tables, so - basically - you get

```
EMP number of rows (14) * (DEPT number of rows - 1) (4 - 1 = 3) = 14 * 3 = 42
```

Now, it depends on what you really want to do, which rows are the ones you're interested in. Maybe it is `NOT IN` which uses a subquery:

```
SQL> select d.rowid, d.deptno, d.dname
  2  from dept d
  3  where d.deptno not in (select e.deptno from emp e);

ROWID                  DEPTNO DNAME
------------------ ---------- --------------
AAAE5nAAEAAAAGmAAD         40 OPERATIONS

SQL>
```

which says: there's no employee who works in department 40, so only one row is returned.

Copied to your case, see if this helps:

```
SELECT 1, cb.ROWID, 'A2CUSTBRIS', 167, 4, CURRENT_DATE, 'MODIFY'
FROM a2custbris cb
WHERE cb.custcatcode NOT IN (SELECT cc.custcatcode
                             FROM a2custcategory cc
                            );
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I have another issue if you are able to help me, this block of code adds way more rows than it's meant to. It adds 797 rows, but there are only 152 rows in the table it's pulling from, and even less rows that actually meet the criteria. Any idea why it's adding so many? It just keeps repeating the same rows.

Comment: I have tried using both NOT IN and <> and they both return 797 rows... I don't really know other ways to get the right rows.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding some more code and explanation. Have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you!Could you take a look at one more thing for me? It's another issue with too many rows being returned. Basically this code is just trying to add rows from the a2product table to the dwprod table if they aren't already in the error table. 

```mysql
INSERT INTO DWPROD (DWPRODID, DWSOURCETABLE, DWSOURCEID, PRODNAME, PRODCATNAME, PRODMANUNAME, PRODSHIPNAME)
SELECT p.prodid, 'a2product', p.rowid, p.prodname, pc.categoryname, m.manuname, s.description
FROM a2product p, a2shipping s, a2manufacturer m, a2prodcategory pc
WHERE p.rowid NOT IN (SELECT source_rowid FROM A2ERROREVENT);
```

Comment: Any help would be hugely appreciated, I'm desperately trying to get this all to work before submitting it for assessment in an hour. My brain hurts from trying to code it all which is why I'm seeking the extra help.

Comment: This code contains 4 tables in the `from` clause without any joins between them which means that it'll produce a Cartesian product (or cross join, whichever term you prefer), resulting in total number of rows equal to [number of rows in the 1st table] * [number of rows in the 2nd table] * ... * [number of rows in the last table]. Join them to avoid this.